# Overriding a function on a javascript object's property

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

How would you override a function on a javascript object when the function is on another object within the parent object.

Example:

```
function TestingABC() {
     this.events = { finish: function() { console.log("FINISHED"); } };
}

function TestingXYZ() {
     TestingABC.call(this);
}

TestingXYZ.prototype = Object.create(TestingABC.prototype);
```

How would I override the events.finish function on TestingXYZ to run the parent (TestingABC) code along with some new code that I need to write?

Comment: `var old = this.events.finish; this.events.finish = function() { console.log('new function'); old.call(this); };` ?

Comment: @RobG why did you delete your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `events` object is property of the instance, not on the prototype, you could employ a technique similar to *monkey patching*, where you store a reference to the current function, then override the current function with one that can call the old one in addition to doing other stuff.

e.g.

```
function TestingABC() {
     this.events = { finish: function() { console.log("FINISHED"); } };
}

function TestingXYZ() {
     TestingABC.call(this);
     var superEvents = this.events;
     this.events = {
         finish: function () {
              superEvents.finish();
              doMyStuff();
         }
     };
}

TestingXYZ.prototype = Object.create(TestingABC.prototype);
```

Comment: What about `TestingXYZ.prototype.constructor = TestingXYZ`? :D

Comment: @Badacadabra I'm not sure what you mean, sorry.

Comment: No problem... ;) In fact, this is generally a good idea to "remap" the constructor when using inheritance in ES5. `Object.create()` takes the whole prototype of the parent "class", which includes the parent constructor. But the true constructor of the "subclass" is not the parent constructor... This is where the above code is useful. :)

Answer (score 0):

`.events` is an instantiated property of the `TestingABC()` constructor - so you can amend the value once you have an instantiation of it.

Perhaps something like this is what you're after?...

```
function TestingABC() {
     this.events = {
        finish: function() {
            console.log('ABC FINISHED');
        },
        other: function() {
            console.log('ABC OTHER');
        }
    };
}

function TestingXYZ() {
     TestingABC.call(this);
}

TestingXYZ.prototype = Object.create(TestingABC.prototype);

TestingXYZ.prototype.callEvents = function() {
    this.events.finish();
    this.events.other();
}

var test1 = new TestingABC();
var test2 = new TestingXYZ();

test2.events.finish = function() {
    console.log('XYZ FINISHED');
};

test1.events.finish();
test1.events.other();
//-> ABC FINISHED
//-> ABC OTHER

test2.callEvents();
//-> XYZ FINISHED
//-> ABC OTHER
```